# WinCE 6 Stream Device Driver: CreateFile() causes GetLastError=1359

Tags: driver, windows-ce

i try to migrate a stream device driver from WinCE 5 to WinCE 6, facing problems when opening the interface with CreateFile(). But from the beginning:

I added the following registry information to the Platform.reg:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\MyDriver\DRV]
"Index"=dword:1
"DLL"="MyDriver.DLL"
"Prefix"="DRV"
```

In Platform.bib i included my driver as follows:

```
MyDriver.dll      $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\MyDriver.dll                   NK  SHK
```

The driver is added to the dirs file of my OS design and i can successfully build the driver in my Visual Studio Solution.

In my application i manually load the driver by ActivateDeviceEx:

```
#define DRIVERSHELL_REG_KEY (TEXT("Drivers\\MyDriver\\DRV"))    

hDriverShell = ActivateDeviceEx( DRIVERSHELL_REG_KEY,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            NULL
                            );
```

The result here is neither 0 nor INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, so i think the driver is loaded successfully.

When i try to open the driver with CreateFile():

```
hDS = CreateFile(TEXT("DRV1:")
        ,   GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE
        ,   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
        ,   NULL
        ,   OPEN_EXISTING
        ,   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
        ,   0);
```

GetLastError returns 1359. The error states the following:

1359 ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR
(Description: The security account database contains an internal inconsistency)

As mentioned, the driver is migrated form a working WinCE 5 Image. All stream interface functions are declared in the source code of the driver (xxx_init(), xxx_open()...). Does anyone have an idea what may cause this error or at which detail i need to have a closer look?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers! I successfully debugged the image and the implemented driver now. "ActivateDeviceEx()" calls "XXX_Init()" and "CreateFile()" calls "XXX_Open()". I did set a breakpoint in each driver function and reached it. So far so good. I located the problem now that the function "HIDDeviceAttach()" is not called when i plug the device (a joystick, the driver is a HID Joystick Driver). Then some handles are 0 and XXX_Open() sets an internal error as LastError. How does the OS know which device is plugged at the USB-Bus and which HIDDeviceAttach() function has to be called (Mouse/Keyboard/Joystick)? 
[btw: shall i open a new question regarding this?]

Answer (score 0):

Martin, 
         You added your driver details here [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\MyDriver\DRV] and in the code you are giving

```
#define DRIVERSHELL_REG_KEY (TEXT("Drivers\\Drivers\\MyDriver\\DRV"))
```

may be the two 'Drivers' is a spelling mistake bcoz you mentioned the `ActivateDeviceEx` is not returning any error. If you want to make sure this you can print the first parameter ie '`LPCTSTR pContext`' in your `DRV_Init()`, which gives the registry location where your driver is in the active key (like Drivers\Active\66)

And normally `CreateFile()` takes 7 arguments but you mentioned only 6. Mistake or purposefully done ?

Comment: Right, i changed my driver name to a global name "Drivers" before put it on the internet. In my sources i am sure to have the right path. Thank you for this hint.

Comment: The second hint is also right, and again a matter of copying. In my sourcecode i have 7 arguments:

 hDS = CreateFile(  TEXT("JOY1:")
      , GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE
      , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
      , NULL
      , OPEN_EXISTING
      , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
      , 0);

Comment: May it be possible that i cant open the driver in the application directly, because of the changes in WinCE 6 (no direct access to kernel drivers)?

Comment: Kernel-mode code can display a user interface with help of UI proxy device driver (SYSGEN_UIPROXY). So the application can directly access the kernel mode drivers. Now it is better to debug your driver code as 'Valter Minute' told

Comment: Ok sorry, i didnt recognise your comment here. I start debugging now.

Comment: What I meant is your application can communicate with the kernel mode driver as if it is a user mode driver. And you mentioned "ActivateDeviceEx() returns a GetLastError of 2" which means your driver mentioned in the registry, ie MyDriver.DLL is not included in the OS image, You can check whether it is included or not by opening your NK with platform builder (File->Open->File: NK.bin then check in the (All Files) section).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use a debug OS and put breakpoints on your XXX_Init and XXX_Open entry points to check what is going wrong in the driver code?
If you can't use KITL to connect you can still build a debug version of the driver (you can use the COMPILE_DEBUG directive in your sources file if you want to keep the rest of the OS in release) and enable debug messages that will be sent to your debug serial port.

Comment: Yes, this will be the next step to go into the init and open functions and see whats going on there. But another point: If i add 
"Flags"=dword:10
to the Platform.reg then the driver should run in User-Mode. If i do so (thats the only change), ActivateDeviceEx() returns a GetLastError of 2, which means, that the driver wasnt found!? Does anyone has an explanation here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I missed your answer in my inbox. It may be that you set the "K" flag for your driver in the bib file and this prevents it from being loaded in user-mode. Set it to Q (Kernel/User) or remove it if you'll use it only in user mode.